# Unity 2018 - 2D Sprite - Scaling and Rotating base on different pivots

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite, image-rotation, image-scaling

I am a new in the Unity world and I have a question regarding Scaling and Rotating.

In Unity I can scale and rotate based on the object pivot.

But in my animation I am scaling the object with bottom pivot and I would like to rotate this object around the central point/pivot of this object. The issue is that this object is has only one pivot which I already moved to the bottom, because of the scaling.

Any trick for that?

thanks

Central Pivot is not working: ibb.co/SvQCQmc

Comment: Change the pivot from pivot to center as required and back again? (On the bar at the top of unity)

Comment: that´s what I tried, It looks it works , when I am turning this 2D object by my hand but when I press animation it use the other pilvot again - despite the fact that during recording it did something completely different :(

Comment: rather than specifically use animations why not do it via code

Comment: here is it: https://ibb.co/SvQCQmc

Comment: That's because you recorded the animation on that pivot. Animation is just a recording that plays the same. You need to rotate it via code if your pivots are changing, or create animations for both pivots. I'd recommend the former one.

Comment: But as you can see, in my gif , the recording is not the same as original movemwnt during the recording thats what disturbs me.

Comment: You may need to add a custom pivot. Watch this video maybe it will help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=itIh8PYGP7w

Comment: ok that , works I did with the extra empty object, thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

In the inspector you can edit the sprites pivot.

I advise you to check this official page.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpriteEditor.html